# Multiprocessing hangs when Number of processes is increased

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand multiprocessing in python.

I made a test program that finds the max number from a set of lists. 
It works fine for a limited number of processes, but at some point the program hangs if I increase the number to say 5000 processes.

Am I doing something wrong? Why does it hang if I increase the number of processes?

Here is my code:

```
from  multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import numpy.random as npyrnd

def getMaxRand(_num, shared_dict):
    '''
    create a list of random numbers
    picks max from list
    '''
    print 'starting process num:', _num
    rndList = npyrnd.random(size= 100)
    maxrnd = max(rndList)
    print 'ending process:', _num
    shared_dict[_num] = maxrnd



if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    manager = Manager()
    shared_dict= manager.dict()  
    for i in range(50): #hangs when this is increased to say 5000
        p = Process(target=getMaxRand, args=( i, shared_dict))
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()


    print shared_dict
```

EDIT:Having read some of the responses, Its clear that I can not just arbitrarily create many processes, and hope that multiprocessing library queues them for me. So a follow up question for me is how can I determine a max number of processes that i can run simultaneously?

Comment: Any program will hang with that many processes, if you're using a regular, everyday PC. The only solution for that is using something with an obscene amount of cores, like Cuda.

Comment: I don't know why it hangs at that point ... but why do you want to start 5000 processes?

Comment: What would you expect your system to do when you throw so much work at it?  You're probably just saturating your CPU or bus.  You're also going to bottleneck writing to `shared_dict` at some point, even with enough cores to handle all the processes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I guess I assumed that multiprocessing handles multiple processes and Queues them automatically. Looks like I need to manually manage and Quene my processes.

Comment: @mgilson I am trying to parallelize a clustering algorithm and its not uncommon to have many clusters in the orders of 100s or even 1000s.

Comment: @adi -- Look into a `multiprocessing.Pool`.  The `Pool` objects have a variety of methods which can be useful for managing the queue for you.

Comment: @adi, if the work for each process is cpu-bound, you basically won't do better than the number of cores, i.e. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.

Comment: What OS are you using? There's a pretty big difference in how `multiprocessing` works between Windows and Unix-like systems (in terms of overhead and limits on various solutions). There can also be system-dependent limits on things like the number of processes you can spawn. Also, your `Pool` solution doesn't actually create 5000 processes, just 8. It simply reuses those processes to do 5000 jobs (queuing the ones it hasn't got to yet). This distinction may or may not matter to you.

Comment: @Blckknght Im using windows 7, on a 8 core machine. I could have used multiprocessing.cpu_count(). Also It looks like re-using processes is much faster than creating new processes.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to overcome the large number of processes hanging my PC.
It appears to be working for a fairly large number of processes (I tested upto 50000)

This is how i approached the problem:

```
from  multiprocessing import  Pool
import numpy.random as npyrnd


full_result = {}

def getMaxRand(_num):
    '''
    create a list of random numbers
    picks max from list
    '''
    print 'starting process num:', _num
    rndList = npyrnd.random(size= 100)
    maxrnd = max(rndList)
    print 'ending process:', _num

    return (_num, maxrnd)

def accumulateResults(result):
    print 'getting result' , result
    full_result[result[0]] = result[1]

def doProcesses():
    pool = Pool(processes=8)    
    for i in range(5000): #if I increase this number will it crash?
        pool.apply_async(getMaxRand, args=( i, ), callback=accumulateResults)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    doProcesses()
    print 'FINAL:', full_result
```

Thanks @mgilson and @Kylo for pointing me in this direction.